# How to choose different Redis connection when using Laravel Cache facade

Tags: caching, redis, connection, laravel-5.8

I have several Redis connections configured in my project in config/database.php file.

One is for session, other is for application cache and third is default one. When I use Cache::get() or Cache::put() how can I select which Redis connection I want to use? Is this possible?

I am using laravel 5.8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use the cache facade, you will use the default settings under `config\cache` 
by default

When you specify to use redis store, you will use cache connection by default

Therefore you need to use something like `Cache::driver($yourStoreName)->get($yourKeyName)`

My suggestion is to use the Redis facade:

```
Redis::connection('cache')->get($yourKeyName);
```